# Configure nginx to send back index.html for a 404

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, http-status-code-404, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to send back my index.html to the client when my nginx (acting as reverse proxy for my express application servers and to serve static assets) gets back a 404 from the API that it's proxying for.

This is the relevant server block for my nginx configuration:

```
server {
  listen  80;
  root    /var/www/dist;
  index   index.html index.htm;

  location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
    expires 1d;
  }

  location @proxy {
    proxy_set_header    Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header    Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header    Host $host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header    X-NginX-Proxy true;

    proxy_http_version  1.1;
    proxy_redirect      off;
    proxy_pass          http://node-app;
    proxy_cache_bypass  $http_upgrade;
  }

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @proxy;
  }

  error_page 404 = /;

}
```

Just to specify, the use case here is I'm using React Router with HistoryLocation enabled, so right now if I try to refresh on one of my routes (like `example.com/signup`), I get back a 404.

Answer (score 0):

When using an express server (including via nginx), send back index.html as a catch-all, after handling other file types:

```
  app.get( /\.(js|css|png|jpg|svg)$/, function(req, res) {
    var uri = url.parse( req.url, true, false );

    sendFile( res, uri.pathname );
  } );

  //------------- return index.html for everything else so routing works

  app.get( '*', function(req, res) {
    sendFile( res, `${htmlPath}index.html` );
  } );
```

If just using nginx directly (without express), return index.html for 404 errors:

```
  error_page 404 /index.html;
        location = /40x.html {
  }
```